# Get a property value with automation id

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I have a toggle button and I want to get his toggle state value with his automation id. How can I do that?

[image: ToggleButton]

Comment: Please do not post pictures but copy the code to your post. What do you mean by "get his toggle state value with his automation id"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the method below :

```
var toggleState= app.Query (c => c.Marked("FilterWalkButton").Invoke ("ToggleState").Value<bool> ()).First ();
Assert.IsTrue (toggleState, "Button is not toggled");
```

Comment: Im Getting an exception
ArgumentException: Can not convert Object to Boolean.